# Javascript object property undefined when it's clearly existing

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm facing a weird situation right now, if I do this within my EJS template:

`<%= JSON.stringify(course.results[0]) %>`

that print me the following:

```
{
  "user_id": "900",
  "trainingpath_id": "25",
  "sco_id": "1",
  "nb": "11",
  "date": "25/07/2018 14:14",
  "date_last_update": "21/08/2018 13:10",
  "lesson_status": "passed",
  "spent_time": "278",
  "score": "100",
  "progression": "100",
  "unique_sco_id": "427"
}
```

But if I do this:

`<%= JSON.stringify(course.results[0].score) %>`

I receive an error telling me that it `Cannot read property 'score' of undefined`

Someone ever experienced that ?

Actual template page :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row heading-box">
        <div class="col">
            <h1><span id="introduction">Progress<br></span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-box">
        <div class="col">
            <% if (Array.isArray(sessions)) { %>
                <% sessions.map(session=>{ %>
                    <div class="session-box">
                        <h4 class="session-title"><i class="fal fa-chevron-double-right title-indicator"></i> <%= session.name; %> </h4>
                        <% session.courses.map(course=>{%>
                            <div class="course-box">
                            <span class="fa-stack course-thumbnail-stack">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle course-thumbnail-circle ready fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fal fa-play-circle course-thumbnail-action ready fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                                <img src="<%= session.details[0].thumbnail_link.indexOf(lms_url) > -1 ? '' : `${lms_url}/` %><%= session.details[0].thumbnail_link %>" class="course-thumbnail">
                                <h4> <%= course.titre; %></h4>
                                <p>
                                    Duration : <%= (session.details[0].typical_learning_time_duration || 0) / 60 %> mins<br/>
                                    Score : <% if ('results' in course && Array.isArray(course.results)) { %><%= JSON.stringify(course.results[0], null, '\t') %><% } else { %><%= '0' %><% } %>%
                                </p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg start-course" onclick="window.location='<%= course.lms_url %>>'">Start</button>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            </div>
                        <%});%>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first code is telling you that `course.results[0]` is not `undefined`, the second is telling you that `course.results[0]` **is** `undefined`. We are missing something. Are both these snippets in the same place in the code?

Comment: I added my template page code so you can see.

Comment: Actually `Score : <% if ('results' in course && Array.isArray(course.results)) { %><%= JSON.stringify(course.results[0], null, '\t') %><% } else { %><%= '0' %><% } %>%` the end results should be to just print the score, but I'm searching why it's not working.

Comment: try checking the length of the `course.results` before printing `<%= JSON.stringify(course.results[0].score) %>`?

Comment: `<% if ('results' in course && Array.isArray(course.results) && course.result.length > 0) { %><%= course.results[0].score %><% } else ...`

Comment: Now I get `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` It's like the object is destroyed after it pass the if... but... what's the purpose of if then :D lolll :|

Comment: OH! It work. Sorry @jackjop there was a typo in your version that I copied. results with a S :D !

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer @jackjop :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there is nothing wrong with the scope you have, so probably you're having a problem with the array `course.results` sometimes, meaning it might have no elements. So to avoid that just add `length` check as suggested by @Kosala Nuwan Perera

Also you don't need to `stringify` the score as it is a string already.

Try:

```
Score : <% if ('results' in course && Array.isArray(course.results) && course.results.length > 0) { %><%= course.results[0].score %><% } else { %><%= '0' %><% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you'd get `property 'score' of undefined` is if your `results[0]` was undefined.

I'd suggest doing:

```
if(course && course.results && course.results.length) {
    course.results[0].score
}
```